# How to pronounce Alois in A Dog of Flanders?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, names, literature

The e-book I have downloaded from Amazon has Alois, but Wikipedia seems to have Aloise. I do not know which one is correct in the first place. I shall assume Alois is the correct one.

A Dog of Flanders is an 1872 English novel, which takes place in Belgium. A Japanese adaptation animation is widely more popular in my country. In the animation version, her name is [a.ro.a]. Since the Japanese language lacks the distinction of [r] and [l] or dipthong like [rwa] , if the Japanese producer was correct, her name should be pronounced like [alwa].

I have learned French a little, so if one pronounces Alois in the French way, it should be like that. But, I am not sure whether the English author intended that or  not. I searched Google for the pronunciation, but the top result web site gave me three or more alternative pronunciations for that name.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the pronunciation of a Dutch name.

Comment: I meant how English readers pronounce that name, because the novel is written in English by a British author. If there is no consented pronunciation among English speakers, I will withdraw this question.

Comment: I think there's a good question about how foreign names are used within English to be found by generalising this question so that Alois is only an example of the more general question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In British English, the correct pronunciation of the French name *Aloïs* is more-or-less how the French say it: [***ah-lo-ISS***](http://fr.forvo.com/word/alo%C3%AFs/) (though some may mistakenly pronounce it *Alwa*). *Aloïse* (pronounced *ah-lo-EEZ*) is commonly a girl's name in French.

As has been pointed out in the comments, however, the different languages spoken in Belguim makes it difficult to work out the intended pronunciation. It may well be that it's something closer to the German *Alois* (*AH-lo-ees*). But this too is a boy's name.

Probably, given the setting, the language intended is Flemish, which is close to Dutch, which is closer to German than French. I can't find any record of *Alois* being used as a Dutch girl's name though either. Maybe the author's just made it up.

In an interesting note, the name *Alois* comes from the Old Frankish name *[Chlodowig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clovis_(given_name))* meaning "famous in battle". It's the same name that gives us the French *Clovis* and *Louis* (pronounced *Cloevie* and *Louie*), the English *Louis* (*Lewis*), the German *Ludwig*, and the Italian *Luigi*, [along with many others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_(given_name)). *Clovis* was Latinized to *Aloysius* and thence to *Alois*.

Comment: It's quite likely not the French name *Alois* but the German name *Alois*, pronounced more like *AW-lo-ees*.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Should have done more research before assuming French.

Comment: Given that the author's first language was French and she styled herself French (using both a French form of her given name in daily life, and a different French pen-name), I'd say the French is probably what she intended. But given the location in Flanders the German form remains quite likely too. I know of nothing that indicates the actual form of the name originally intended.

Comment: I have never heard a French person pronounce _Aloïs_ as [al'wa]. I know just one French Aloïs, but both he and everyone I've heard say his name have pronounced it [alo'is], with three syllables, and sounding much like _Louise_ at the end (but with [s] instead of [z]). Wiktionary’s French entry on the name also has only this pronunciation, and both the spelling (with the trema) and the etymology indicate it.

Comment: ...thanks to the hive mind this answer just keeps getting less and less inaccurate.

Comment: It seems the novel itself is not so well-known to English speakers. Then I think my question has little meaning. In Korea and Japan this story is very famous and almost everybody pronounces her name like Aroa due to the influence of the animation. If there is no such well-known pronunciation among English speakers, I think I can pronounce it in anyway I think is correct.